# Relationship between the slit width $w$ and source distance $d$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, double-slit-experiment

[image]

I read in a text of optics Eugene Hecht where I got that, **missing fringes in a double-slit interference experiment results when diffraction minima cancel interference maxima.**

Is there any relationship between the slit width w and source distance d, so I can tell when the maxima could be missing?

Comment: It's not found in Hecht's text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my (ancient) copy of Hecht and Zajac (1980), the answer is found in figure 10.18. It shows that for slit spacing $a$ and slit width $b$, peaks in the diffraction pattern are spaced $\lambda/d$ while the first zero due to the finite width is at $\lambda/b$. In the figure, $a = 3b$ and the third peak is suppressed:

[image]